# WinDbg address summary failed

Tags: .net, debugging, windbg

I'm getting following error when looking at full memory crash dump file taken on user machine (Windows Server 2008 SP2):

0:000> !address -summary

Failed to map Heaps (error 80004005)

I'm running WinDbg 6.12.0002.633 X86 on Windows XP Pro (SP3).
SOS and other commands seems to work.
Appreciate any advice.

Thanks,
Michal

Comment: Do you have access to OllyDbg or Ida Pro? They might be able to give some insight.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. AFAIK, it looks like a bug in this version of windbg, or perhaps something missing in the public system symbols used by windbg. I now use the previous version of windbg (6.11.1.404) to execute !address.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Developer Preview of WDK 8. It contains a newer version of WinDbg (6.2.8102.0) which fixes this issue.

Comment: Actually funny that 6.2 is newer than 6.12, but I guess it's true.